# Graviational Lensing Data

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, gravitational-lensing

Can anyone provide me with (or point me to) real life gravitational lensing data that I can plug in to the first equation on this page (the standard lensing equation):  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens together with the luminous mass and distance to the galaxy(s).  I've looked for papers online and have not found any simple data that can be readily plugged in to the equation (I am not familiar with the details of how exactly the lensing is measured and have gotten lost in the mountains of data in the papers).  Thanks

Comment: That's not how life works. You'll need some kind of correlation algorithm that looks for something that could be a solution of this formula based on background star data.

Comment: So there is no data that is just the angle of deflection and radius at which the deflection was measured?

Comment: Nope. Try http://spacewarps.org/ for a citizen-project, or a paper I found http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.3127 that tries to set up an algorithm, although this is very technical. Once someone has analyzed and found the distorted rings, you can apply your formula.