# Are there any experimental data for light bending angle?

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, gravitational-lensing

The gravitational lensing formula is given by equation $a=4M/r$. Is there any experimental data for this equation. I am trying to plot a curve for this equation and the real experimental data and check for the accuracy. I would really appreciate a table of data for the angle of deflection at each $r$ and $M$ if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much exact duplicate of the unanswered questions http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147004/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194211.

Comment: Actually, the comments in the 2nd of the two I linked is probably most relevant, specifically [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194211/gravitational-lensing-experimental-data#comment414351_194211): *You don't find much raw (or even processed data) on the open web. Even experiments which have a mandate to make the work public (like the Sloan Digital Sky Survey) require you to dig around a little bit to find out how the data you want is labeled. And that is not a problem: the amount of work involved in getting the data is tiny compared to the work involved in analyzing it.*

Comment: @KyleKanos, The problem is I don't know where to look. I have found nothing.

Comment: Well that's really science for you. Data from experiments are usually kept under lock & key so that one doesn't get scooped. The [SpaceWarps group](http://spacewarps.org/#/about) seems to be a promising avenue though.